# Why is the sample mean a statistic?

Tags: statistics

A statistic is any (measurable) function of the data.

When the argument "n is known" is given for justifying that ${1\over n}\sum\limits_{i=1} ^n X_i$ is a statistic, is it really a valid argument?

The argument goes like: "$n$ is known, so the statistic is only a function of $X_1,\dots,X_n$ and not $n$".

Can you construct a function of $n$ variables that outputs the number $n$?

Say $n=3$, and let the variables be called $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$, say they are real variables. I don't really see a way, unless you allow really unusual rules for constructing your function.

I'm starting to realize, the size of the sample is information that you can get from the sample and it is a function of the sample as a result of that...

Comment: What is your question ? The body does not seem related to the question.

Comment: I don't understand what you want from us with this question.  Did you not already answer it for yourself in the last sentence?  As for "*can you construct a function...that outputs the number $n$*" the answer is  of course.  Even in the event that the number of variables is itself variable... you could write your function as rather than being of the form $f(a,b,c,\dots,n)$ to be of the form $f((a,b,c,\dots,n))$ where what is being passed in to the function is a single argument, that argument being a tuple which we can tell the size of.

Comment: I think the question may be for example if you say that $\sum X_i$ is a sufficient statistic for a sample from a Poisson distribution, then you are implicitly assuming $n$ is known

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the sample is usually decided by the data collector and is implicitly known, unless it is itself a random variable and is somehow a part of the sample. In the latter case, some form of encoding ensures that the sample is "readable".

Answer (score 0):

I think this deserves some clarification. In the simplest setting, a statistical model is given by the data of a measurable space $E$ and a set of probability measures $P_\theta$ on $E$, indexed by some set $\Theta$. A statistics is any measurable function with domain space $E$ (and codomain some measurable space). In particular, it may depend on $E$. The only constraint is that it should not be depend on $\theta$ (otherwise it would be a function with domain $E\times \Theta$ and not $E$). Here, $E=\mathbb{R}^n$ (or $(\mathbb{R}^d)^n$ if the observations are vectors). Hence, the function $(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in E \mapsto n$ is indeed a measurable function, as would be the function $(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in E\mapsto 17$: the size of the sample is indeed a statistics.